# Google rich cards requested dateCreated for movies, but it is not published?

Tags: google-search-console, schema.org, structured-data, rich-cards

We have a website that focuses on movies. In Google Search Console > Rich Cards they requested `dateCreated` for movies, but this information is not published anywhere? (IMDb, official website, wikipedia, etc.)

We are opting to use the movie `premier date` as an alternative to `date created` and tag it under `dateCreated`.

Any suggestions?

**Update:**

Below is a screenshot to the issue. Please don't mind the `director` field, that is already resolved. The `dateCreated` is the remaining issue.

[image]

Comment: Does this Rich Cards section in the Google Search Console say for which rich result the `dateCreated` property is required (or just recommended)?

Comment: @unor its a non-critical issue `Rich Cards > Film > Missing or invalid field: dateCreated (Non-critical issue)`. I have around 183 items that are tagged as `Enhanceable cards` because of this field.

Comment: The info of Google guide to TV and Movie do not have requirements or even recommendations for the dateCreated. Please check it https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/tv-movie

Comment: @nikant25 hello, I have already read that link and also did not see the `dateCreated` item. I have updated the question, added a screenshot of the issue to make things clearer.

Comment: @Jo E. This is probably due to the syntactical error of the markup. It is difficult to determine only on the basis of the screenshot.

Comment: @nikant25 well I used `json-ld` for this project and it is reading correctly in google's structured data testing tool. And like the testing tool, `dateCreated` is also being flagged as a warning with a notice `The dateCreated field is recommended. Please provide a value if available.`. Anyway I wanted to fix this so that I can change the cards from `Enhanceable` to `Fully enhanced cards`.

Comment: Try using this generator JSON-LD https://www.schemaapp.com/tools/jsonld-schema-generator/